# How to choose an XML Node? (Using LINQ, XPath, anything is fine)

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML like below :

```
<Decide Name="MemoryCheck" CommonUnit="MB">
    <Decision CellColor="Red" Status="Critical" Exp="&lt;=100" />
    <Decision CellColor="Yellow" Status="Warning" Exp="&lt;=200 &amp; &gt;100"/>
    <Decision CellColor="Green" Status="OK" Exp="&gt;200" />
</Decide>
```

For Input  50 MB, Output returned should be "Critical-Red"
For Input 142 MB, Output returned should be "Warning-Yellow"
For Input 212 MB, Output returned should be"OK-Green"

How to go about this using C# ??
Xml Name is "Decide.xml" and Code I have now :

```
XmlDocument xmldecide = new XmlDocument();    
xmldecide.Load("C:\\Decide.xml");
XmlNodeList decidelist = xmldecide.GetElementsbyTagName("Decide");
XmlNode xdecide = decidelist[0];

string input = "50"; // Unit in MB
// Now I have to display the desired O/P "Critical-Red"
string input = "142"; // Unit in MB
// Now I have to display the desired O/P "Warning-Yellow"
string input = "212"; // Unit in MB
// Now I have to display the desired O/P "OK-Green"
```

Comment: How do you parse/read the XML in C# currently, are you using `XDocument`? Post some relevant C# code providing more context on where the "XML node selection" logic would be applied

Comment: you should parse your xml first `XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);`

Comment: The entire Xml Element is present as : 
XmlNode xdecide = <Decide> .. </Decide> ; This XML element is part of an XML file which I loaded using XmlDocument

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to reflect what you are asking for in your code snippet.  You have the XML nodes `xdecide` is the first node and you can get all the nodes easily.  Are you asking how to write the logic to parse your XML nodes to figure out which one is relevant for each input?

Comment: @SteveMitcham If you see the expected result, all I want to do is to "select a node" based on the input and the exp attribute. Once the node is selected, I can easily choose CellColor attribute's value and concat it with the status attribute's value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion - If you have control of that xml you should consider creating a min and max attribute. Having to parse out conditional and integer information from a single attribute is ugly. That said, assuming you can't change the xml, here's a solution. It assumes the conditionals in the attribute are always in a similar format.

```
    public static string AlertLevel(this XDocument decisionDocument, int size)
    {
        var queryResult = decisionDocument.Descendants("Decision");
        foreach (var item in queryResult)
        {
            var expAttribute = item.Attribute("Exp");
            if (expAttribute == null) continue;

            var returnString = CreateResultString(item);

            int minValue;
            int maxValue;
            if (expAttribute.Value.Contains(">") && expAttribute.Value.Contains("<="))
            {
                //evaluate minValue < size > maxValue
                var stringValue = expAttribute.Value.Replace("<=", string.Empty).Replace(">", string.Empty).Trim();
                var stringValueArray = stringValue.Split('&');

                if (int.TryParse(stringValueArray[1], out minValue) &&
                    int.TryParse(stringValueArray[0], out maxValue))
                {
                    if (minValue < size &&
                        size < maxValue)
                        return returnString;
                }
            }
            else if (expAttribute.Value.Contains(">"))
            {
                //evaluate size > value
                var stringValue = expAttribute.Value.Replace(">", string.Empty).Trim();
                if (int.TryParse(stringValue, out maxValue))
                {
                    if (size > maxValue)
                        return returnString;
                }
            }
            else if (expAttribute.Value.Contains("<="))
            {
                //else evaluate size < value
                var stringValue = expAttribute.Value.Replace("<=", string.Empty).Trim();
                if (int.TryParse(stringValue, out minValue))
                {
                    if (size < minValue)
                        return returnString;
                }
            }
        }

        return "No condition was met!";
    }

    private static string CreateResultString(XElement item)
    {
        var statusAttribute = item.Attribute("Status");
        var returnString = statusAttribute == null ? "Status" : statusAttribute.Value;

        var colorAttribute = item.Attribute("CellColor");
        returnString += colorAttribute == null ? "-Color" : "-" + colorAttribute.Value;
        return returnString;
    }
```

usage

```
var xmlDecide =  XDocument.Load("Decide.xml");
Console.WriteLine("50MB: " + xmlDecide.AlertLevel(50));
Console.WriteLine("142MB: " + xmlDecide.AlertLevel(142));
Console.WriteLine("212MB: " + xmlDecide.AlertLevel(212));
```

EDIT: You can use the same code for use with XmlDocument instead of XDocument. Just change "Attribute" to "Attributes.GetNamedItem" and "Descendants" to "GetElementsByTagName"

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string XML = 
                "<Decide Name=\"MemoryCheck\" CommonUnit=\"MB\">" +
                   "<Decision CellColor=\"Red\"    Status=\"Critical\" Exp=\"&lt;=100\" />" +
                   "<Decision CellColor=\"Yellow\" Status=\"Warning\"  Exp=\"&lt;=200 &amp; &gt;100\"/>" +
                   "<Decision CellColor=\"Green\"  Status=\"OK\"       Exp=\"&gt;200\" />" +
                "</Decide>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(XML);

            XmlNodeList  memoryCheck = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Decision");
            foreach(XmlNode decision in memoryCheck)
            {
                Decision newDecision = new Decision();
                Decision.decisions.Add(newDecision);
                newDecision.Cellcolor = decision.Attributes.GetNamedItem("CellColor").Value;
                newDecision.status = decision.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Status").Value;
                newDecision.low = 0;
                newDecision.high = null;
                string exps = decision.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Exp").Value;
                string[] expsArray = exps.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string exp in expsArray)
                {
                    if(exp.StartsWith("<="))
                    {
                            newDecision.high = int.Parse(exp.Substring(exp.IndexOf("=") + 1));
                    }
                    if(exp.StartsWith(">"))
                    {
                            newDecision.low = int.Parse(exp.Substring(exp.IndexOf(">") + 1));
                    }
                }
            }

            Decision result =  Decision.GetBySize(212);


        }
    }
    public class Decision
    {
        public static List<Decision> decisions = new List<Decision>();
        public string Cellcolor { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int? low { get; set; }
        public int? high {get; set;}

        public static Decision GetBySize(int memory)
        {
            Decision newDecision = null;
            foreach(Decision decision in decisions)
            {
                if (memory >= decision.low)
                {
                    if (decision.high == null)
                    {
                        newDecision = decision;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (memory <= decision.high)
                        {
                            newDecision = decision;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return newDecision;
        }
    }


}
```